# Symfony Php: emulate FileUpload and create UploadedFile

Tags: php, symfony

On a Symfony Commandline ContainerAwareCommand I want to emulate a file upload in order to call the following Method:

```
namespace AppUserBundle\Services;

use PcMagas\AppImageBundle\Filters\Crop\CropFilter;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Imagine\Image\ImageInterface;
use PcMagas\AppImageBundle\Filters\Resize\ResizeToLimitsKeepintAspectRatio;
use PcMagas\AppImageBundle\Filters\Resize\ResizeParams;
use PcMagas\AppImageBundle\Loader\ImageLoaderInterface;
use PcMagas\AppImageBundle\Saver\SaverInterface;
use Imagine\Image\Box;

class ProfileImageGenerator implements UploadedFileProcessor
{
    const CROP_PARAMS='crop';

    /**
     * @var CropFilter
     */
    private $crop=null;

    /**
     * @var ThumbnailFilterLoader
     */
    private $thumbnail=null;

    /**
     * @var ResizeParams
     */
    private $resizeParams=null;

    /**
     * @var ImageLoaderInterface
     */
    private $imageLoader=null;

    /**
     * @var SaverInterface
     */
    private $imageSaver=null;

    public function __construct(CropFilter $crop,
                                    ResizeToLimitsKeepintAspectRatio $thumbnail,
                                    ImageLoaderInterface $imageLoader,
                                    SaverInterface $imageSaver,
                                    $thumbnailWidth,
                                    $thumbnailHeight
    ){
        $this->crop=$crop;  
        $this->thumbnail=$thumbnail;

        $this->imageLoader=$imageLoader;
        $this->imageSaver=$imageSaver;

        if($thumbnailWidth>0 && $this->thumbnailHeight>0){      
            $this->resizeParams= new Box($thumbnailWidth,$thumbnailHeight);
        }
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * @see \AppUserBundle\Services\UploadedFileProcessor::process()
     */
    public function process(UploadedFile $f, array $params) 
    {
        $image=$this->openUploadedFileAsImageInterface($f);

                //I implement in such a manner to provide extra prossessings over thumbnail image
        if(isset($params[self::CROP_PARAMS])){
            $image=$this->crop->apply($image, $params[self::CROP_PARAMS]);
        }

        if($this->resizeParams){        
            $image=$this->thumbnail->apply($image,$this->resizeParams);
        }

        return $this->generateFileFromImageInterface($image);
    }

    /**
     * @param UploadedFile $f
     * @return ImageInterface
     */
    private function openUploadedFileAsImageInterface(UploadedFile $f)
    {
        return $this->imageLoader($f->getContents());
    }

    /**
     * @param ImageInterface $image
     * @return Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File
     * @throws RuntimeException
     */
    private function generateFileFromImageInterface(ImageInterface $image)
    {
        $tmpName=tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir()).'.png';
                return $this->imageSaver->save($image); 
    }
}
```

Now I want to see how the method `process` will behave so I created the following `ContainerAwareCommand` In order to emulate a file upload:

```
namespace AppUserBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use AppUserBundle\Services\ProfileImageGenerator;
use PcMagas\AppImageBundle\Filters\Crop\CropParams;

class CreateProfileImageCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('appsuserbundle:create:profile:image')
            ->setDecrtiption("Process a file image like image profile.")
            ->setHelp("This command allows you to generate a file like a process image.")
            ->addArgument('file',InputArgument::REQUIRED,'The image file to process.');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $file=$input->getArgument('file');

        /**
         * @var AppUserBundle\Services\ProfileImageGenerator $container
         */
        $imageGenerator=$this->getContainer()->getDefinition('app_user.thumbnail_generator');

        $cropParams=new CropParams(5,5,10,10);
        $file=null;//How To emulate an uploadedfile with realData?
        $processedFile=$imageGenerator->process($file,[ProfileImageGenerator::CROP_PARAMS=>$cropParams])
    }
}
```

But I am stuck on how to create an Uploadedfile from a filesystem image in order to see whether the image works do you have ansy somt of idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Symfony Api Documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method___construct) ?

```
__construct(string $path, string $originalName, string|null $mimeType = null, int|null $size = null, int|null $error = null, bool $test = false)
```

=>

```
new UploadedFile($path, $originalName, $mimeType, $size, $error, $test);
```

Now you can insert the path you get from the command arguments and pass that through